# How do I register an object with the IApplicationContext in Spring.Net?

Tags: dependency-injection, ioc-container, spring.net

Spring documentation on http://springframework.net/docs/1.3.1/reference/html/objects.html says:

> "In addition to object definitions which contain information on how to
>   create a specific object, the IApplicationContext implementations also
>   permit the registration of existing objects that are created outside
>   the container, by users. This is done by accessing the
>   ApplicationContext's IObjectFactory via the property ObjectFactory
>   which returns the IObjectFactory implementation
>   DefaultListableObjectFactory. DefaultListableObjectFactory supports
>   registration through the methods RegisterSingleton(..) and
>   RegisterObjectDefinition(..)."

I'm trying to access the `ObjectFactory` object after doing the following:

```
var context = ContextRegistry.GetContext();
```

But there is no `ObjectFactory` property. I'm using Spring.Net v1.3.1.20711 and have `Spring.Core` referenced in my project.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ObjectFactory` property is not exposed by the `IApplicationContext` interface, but is part of the `IConfigurableListableObjectFactory` interface.

Your `context` variable will be of *inferred* type `IApplicationContext`, because of the return type of `ContextRegistry.GetContext()`, so in VS it will appear that the `ObjectFactory` property is not available. However, if you take a closer look, you will see that it is an `XmlApplicationContext` that *has* the `ObjectFactory` property, because it implements `IConfigurableListableObjectFactory`. As Sebastian points out in his answer, most (if not all) application contexts implement this interface.

E.g.:

```cs
var ctx = new XmlApplicationContext("objects.xml");
ctx.ObjectFactory.RegisterSingleton("MyObject2", new MyClass() { Name = "MyObject2"});
var o2 = (MyClass)ctx.GetObject("MyObject2");
Assert.AreEqual("MyObject2", o2.Name);
```

Comment: Right - so I just have to cast it to the appropriate type to expose the property?

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Marjin's answer; here is an extension method to get the Factory which I use.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the ObjectFactory from the Spring context.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The context.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IConfigurableListableObjectFactory Factory(this IApplicationContext context)
    {
        return ((IConfigurableApplicationContext)context).ObjectFactory;
    }
```

Comment: That would help if you do this often. I'm not sure if you'd want to do this in regular use of `IApplicationContext`; `IConfigurableApplicationContext` extends `IApplicationContext`, so although this would work for a lot of application contexts, it is not guaranteed to work for each `IApplicationContext`. For an `IApplicationContext` that doesn't implement `IConfigurableApplicationContext` this extension method would throw a cast exception at runtime.

Comment: Although what you state is correct, all contexts provided by spring.net  implement this interface as far as I recall, so as long as you don't use a custom one you'll be safe.